# Error while deploying nextjs app using amplfy

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I get error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/codebuild/output/src133568055/src/skillaro-blog-frontend/.next/server/app'`

Of course, I don't have an `app` folder in `.next` folder but why amplify is looking for that folder in the first place.

I have it working properly in local.

Yaml file:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```